# Twice as many page faults when reading from a large malloced array instead of just storing?

Tags: linux, perf, page-fault

I am doing a simple test on monitoring page faults with the code below, What I don't know is how a simple one line of code below doubled my page fault count.
if I use

```
 ptr[i+4096] = 'A'
```

I got **25,722**  page-faults with perf tool, which is what I expected,
    but if I use

```
tmp = ptr[i+4096]
```

instead, the page-faults doubled to **51,322** 
  I don't how to explain it. Below is the complete code. Thanks!

```
void do_something() {
    int i;
    char* ptr;
    char tmp;
    ptr = malloc(100*1024*1024);
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 100*1024*1024; i+=4096) {

       //ptr[i+4096] = 'A' ;
       tmp = ptr[i+4096];

       for (j = 0 ; j < 4096; j++)
           ptr[i+j] = (char) (i & 0xff); // pagefault
    }
    free(ptr);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    do_something();
    return 0;
}
```

Machine Info:
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                40
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-39
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    10
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 63
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2687W v3 @ 3.10GHz
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               3096.188
BogoMIPS:              6197.81
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              25600K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-9,20-29
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     10-19,30-39

3.10.0-514.32.3.el7.x86_64 #1

Comment: And you compiled without optimization, I guess?  Because you didn't use `volatile` on anything, so it would all optimize away if compile with normal optimization enabled (-O2 or -O3).  So either way you're storing to the stack, because your loop counters won't be optimized into registers.  Anyway, I could see an extra dTLB miss from storing to the stack after a page-fault modifies the HW page tables to wire the new page (if Meltdown mitigation invalidated the TLBs), but not an extra page fault.  IDK why that would happen.

Comment: In case it matters, what Linux version, and what architecture?  Is it x86 with Meltdown / Spectre mitigation?  (And BTW, with optimization the `tmp = ptr[i+4096]` loads would optimize away, but probably not the store version because gcc doesn't detect malloc/free without passing the pointer anywhere as being a dead store.)

Comment: I built it without any optimization. @Peter, Are you able to repeat it on your linux?

Comment: NOTE the `ptr[i+4096]` will cause an out-of-range memory access on the last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`malloc()` will often satisfy requests for memory by asking the OS for new pages, e.g., via [`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). Such pages are generally allocated lazily: no actual page is allocated until the *first access*.

What happens then depends on the type of the first access: when you do a read first, Linux will map in a shared read-only [COW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) page of zeros to satisfy it, and then if you later you write it takes a second fault to allocate the private writeable page.

When you just do the write first, the first step is skipped. That's the usual case since code generally isn't reading from newly allocated memory which has undefined contents (at least when you get it from `malloc`).

Note that the above is a description of how newly allocated pages work in Linux - when you use `malloc` there is another layer: `malloc` will generally try to satisfy requests for blocks the process freed earlier, rather than continually requesting new memory. In the case memory is re-used, it will generally already be paged in and the above won't apply. Of course for your initial big allocation of 1024 MiB, where is no memory to re-use so you can be sure the allocator is getting it from the OS.

Comment: Oh right, and the buffer isn't page-aligned, so the first access to each page is a read at the end of the char-at-a-time loop, not one-per-page write.  (glibc `malloc` usually keeps the first 16 bytes of a page for bookkeeping, so `ptr` is probably something like `0x...0010`)

Comment: @PeterCordes - I don't think alignment matters for this particular code: the read happens at `i + 4096` every loop, and then the rest of the loop writes up to `i + 4095`, so the reads are always running ahead of the writes and so every page will get a read access first, regardless of the alignment of the block returned by `malloc`.

Comment: oops, I was remembering things totally backwards from looking at it yesterday.